# Baseline for measuring Apache Spark jobs execution times

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am fairly new to Apache Spark. I have been using it for several months, but this is my first project that uses it.

I use Spark to compute dynamic reports from data, stored in a NoSQL database (Cassandra). So far I have created several reports and they are computed correctly. Inside them I use `DataFrame` `.unionAll()`, `.join()`, `.count()`, `.map()`, etc.

I am running a 1.4.1 Spark cluster on my local machine with the following setup:

```
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=6
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=8
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=1g
```

I have also populated the database with test data which is around 10-12k records per table.

By using the driver's web UI (http://localhost:4040/), I have noticed that the jobs are taking 40s-50s to execute, so lately I have been researching ways to tune Apache Spark and the jobs.

I have configured Spark to use the `KryoSerializer`, I have set the `spark.io.compression.codec` to `lzf`, I have optimized the jobs as much as I can and as much as my knowledge allows me to.

This led to the jobs taking 20s-30s to compute (which I think is a good improvement). The problem is that because this is my first Spark project, I have no baseline to compare the jobs times, so I have no idea if the execution is slow or fast and whether there is some problem in the code or with the Spark config.

What is the best way to proceed? Is there a graph or benchmark that shows how much time an action with N data should take?

Answer (score -1):

You have to use hive . On top of hive you can put spark . After doing this create temp table in hive for Cassandra table you can perform all type of aggregation and filtering . After doing this you can use hive jdbc connection to get result . It will give  fast result .

Comment: Why should I use Hive with Spark and Cassandra? What is the benefit that I get from Hive?

Comment: You can perform all type of sql query .  Spark cassandra connector use native driver of cassandra . So when you will use hive that also use native driver but you can perform sql type query and i will give also fast result . Read below link carefully                 https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.7/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkSqlJdbcServer.html

Comment: Mainly Spark cassandra connector will take time if you are not filtering data according to sequence of  partition keys of cassandra table mean order of partition keys must be same as you gave at table creation time in where clause and must be in where clause if you are filtering  data . this approach will filter data from server side ,other wise first spark will load all data in memory after perform query .